# How to make a graphic in turtle to Move?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation, turtle-graphics

I have made a graphic in turtle like this:

```py
from turtle import *
from random import randint
left(20)
speed("fastest")
for i in range(36):
    left(120)
    fd(100)
    left(120)
    fd(100)
    left(120)
    fd(100)
    left(10)
```

it makes this:
[image]

now how to make the triangle-circle rotate? Like I want to drag it, and I want it to rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to make the triangle-circle rotate?

By repeatedly clearing it and redrawing it slightly rotated when no one's looking:

```
from turtle import *

def rotate():

    clear()

    for _ in range(36):
        for _ in range(3):
            left(120)
            fd(100)

        left(10)

    update()
    left(1)
    ontimer(rotate, 60)

left(20)
tracer(False)

rotate()

exitonclick()
```

This code is fragile in that several operations can cause screen updates to occur, other than `update()` itself, so rearranging the code or substituting other methods (e.g. `undo()`) might not have the affect you desire.

> I want to drag it

This is trickier and the result you get may depend on your architecture (Unix or Windows.)  We'll make it into a cursor, which is draggable.  But cursors treat their polygons as filled.  So depending on the underlying Tk implementation, your results might vary.  A lot.

```
from turtle import *

def graphic():
    penup()
    tracer(False)
    begin_poly()

    for _ in range(36):
        for _ in range(3):
            left(120)
            fd(100)

        left(10)

    end_poly()
    tracer(True)
    pendown()

    return get_poly()

def drag_handler(x, y):
    ondrag(None)
    goto(x, y)
    ondrag(drag_handler)

register_shape('graphic', graphic())

ondrag(drag_handler)

shape('graphic')
color('black', 'white')

mainloop()
```

[image]

I fear on Windows this cursor may appear as just a large, black blob.

> I want to drag it, and I want it to rotate

And I want to leave that as an exercise for the reader.  But here it is anyway:

```
from turtle import *

def rotate():
    left(1)
    ontimer(rotate, 60)

def graphic():
    penup()
    tracer(False)
    begin_poly()

    for _ in range(36):
        for _ in range(3):
            left(120)
            fd(100)

        left(10)

    end_poly()
    tracer(True)
    pendown()

    return get_poly()

def drag_handler(x, y):
    ondrag(None)
    goto(x, y)
    ondrag(drag_handler)

register_shape('graphic', graphic())

ondrag(drag_handler)

shape('graphic')
color('black', 'white')

rotate()

mainloop()
```

Again, depending on environment, you may be dragging a large, rotating, black blob.  Now that the graphic image is a cursor, the rotation part is *much* simpler.

Comment: can this not be done by rotating colors in the wheel? It is an illusion, right?

Comment: @Programmer, your wheel has no colors.  Design one that does, try what you suggest, and if you run into problems, post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok then, Thanks for the answer. @cdlane

Comment: @Programmer, I can only guess why this question was downvoted.  I thought it worth answering -- the opposite of a downvote in my thinking.  Perhaps they didn't feel you made enough effort code-wise to address your issue (rotation & drag, not drawing) or maybe it was the "Please answer!!" insistence.  Without a companion comment, it's impossible to say.  I understand why folks don't always leave comments with a downvote due to potential negative gamesmanship.  If you've had other questions or answers downvoted, consider how they differ from your upvoted ones.  And just keep trying.  (Or edit.)